# Retrofit - unable to get a result value OUT of onResponse

Tags: android, retrofit

The code below works, I've checked and double checked.

However, I can't return the results on the parent method.

```
public String[] getLatestStatus(String protocol) {
    final String[] ress = {""};
    ApiInterface apiService =
            ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<SolicitationResponse> call = apiService.getProtocol(protocol, mMainVariables.getAPI_KEY());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<SolicitationResponse>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SolicitationResponse> call, Response<SolicitationResponse> response) {
            List<Solicitation> c = response.body().getData();

           ress[0] = c.get(0).getStatus();
           ress[1] = c.get(0).getReply();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<SolicitationResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }

    });
    return ress;
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to get a particular value out, the above result is always null. I have also tried casting it on a global private variable to no avail.

If I do a `Log.i("Status", c.get(0).getStatus());` instead of inserting it on the array, the result is the actual value.

I even tried only returning a single value, but wasn't able to.

Now that I think about it, enqueue is Async, does that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Post your full code and where you are calling from..

Comment: MainActivity onCreate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not return asynchronous data from the method that you are calling.

You should do it inside the retrofit response callback, after getting response from the API.

When you have some API call it will get executed on different thread
ie. **background thread** it may take longer to get response.

Secondly when you call a method to execute some kind of API call it will be executed on **MAIN-Thread** ie. **UI Thread**.

so you need to wait for the response of the background thread but we shouldn't block UI thread otherwise app may get unresponsive.

When you receive the data in the background thread than you have the opportunity for using this data on Ui thread via onResponse or onFailure callback.

```
    public String[] getLatestStatus(String protocol) {
        final String[] ress = {""};
        ApiInterface apiService =
                ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<SolicitationResponse> call = apiService.getProtocol(protocol, mMainVariables.getAPI_KEY());
        call.enqueue(new Callback<SolicitationResponse>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<SolicitationResponse> call, Response<SolicitationResponse> response) {
                List<Solicitation> c = response.body().getData();

               ress[0] = c.get(0).getStatus();
               ress[1] = c.get(0).getReply();
//On this place only you can utilise the data
dummyUpdateData(ress);

            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<SolicitationResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }

        });
        return ress;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Maybe give me an example towards the right direction?

Comment: i have updated my answer, let me know if it is helpful to understand

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether its the best solution but i think listener pattern should work here..

After onresponse

```
myListener.onResponse(data);
```

And in main activity

```
Implement and override Listener
```

And pass listener to method